# Approximating a recurrence relation with a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion

I would like to approximate a recurrence relation of an arbitrary type
$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n), \quad x_n\in \mathbb{C}$$
with a differential equation of an $k$th order. The sequence $x_n$ is assumed to be bounded.

One of the solutions could be to use a Taylor expansion for $x_{n+1}$:
$$
x_{n+1}=x_{n}+x_{n}'+\frac{1}{2!}x_{n}''+\frac{1}{3!}x_{n}'''+...+\frac{1}{k!}x_n^{(k)}, 
$$
The resulting differential equation would look like this:
$$
x+x'+...+\frac{1}{k!}x^{(k)}=f(x).
$$
The method kind of works, but I do not know what initial conditions would be appropriate for the differential equation and if there are any better ways to approximate a recurrence relation with a differential equation. Does anyone know if this topic was researched by anyone?

Comment: There is some theory about connecting a diffeomorphism to the flow of a dynamical system. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438039, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967153, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145523, ... If $f(x)-x$ is small, you could consider the recursion as the Euler method of a corresponding ODE, and add correction terms inverting the truncation error of the method. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642671,

Comment: That last link was really helpful. Thank you.